UUID does not exist after updating to 6.8.0-39, update-initramfs on 6.8.0-38 could not open modules.builtin
I'm pretty new to Linux so I'll just give the step by step.
After running
sudo apt full-upgrade, it updated a lot of packages (I assume this was to update to 6.8.0-39), and then it said some packages required a reboot to complete. Upon reboot I was greeted with BusyBox to find that
ALERT! UUID=XXXX does not exist. Dropping to shell!

At this point I searched the web for solutions, following the solutions of a similar post I booted into 6.8.0-38 from advanced options in GRUB which worked and then ran sudo apt-get clean and checked df -h to check that that none of my filesystems were at 100%
Then finally I ran
sudo update-initramfs -k 6.8.0-39-generic -u

To find that
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-39-generic
cat: /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_arUoPY/lib/modules/6.8.0-39-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
W: Can't find modules.builtin.modinfo (for locating built-in drivers' firmware, supported in Linux >=5.2)
depmod: WARNING: could not open modules.order at /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_arUoPY/lib/modules/6.8.0-39-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open modules.builtin at /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_arUoPY/lib/modules/6.8.0-39-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open modules.builtin.modinfo at /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_arUoPY/lib/modules/6.8.0-39-generic: No such file or directory

This is as far as the solution I was following had helped as this was the final step given. I would post more of what I can see in BusyBox when booting into 6.8.0-39 but I'm unsure of how to copy the text I see there into here.
